# How to convert the python object returned from mysql connector to a simple tuple

Tags: python, mysql, tuples

We have a database of voter data with about 2 million records that is completely replaced regularly and we just create a new database while keeping previous versions. The newest version has an identical schema, but the column 'birth_date' does not have any data. The primary key is 'voter_id.' We decided to add the previous version's birth_date to the new database.

We could do a join, but decided to use python to read the old database (adv_032021), SELECT 'voter_id' and 'birth_date' and UPDATE 'birth_date' where 'voter_id' matches. It is stated in many sources that the Mysql connector returns a tuple containing each 'row.' It turns out only to be conceptually true, what gets returned is a python object that contains the tuple. And my problem is that I can't find a simple way to extract the tuple to UPDATE the more recent database.

The following code does not work, which is an intuitive try. I've tried a number of things that don't cause any nominal errors, they just don't work. I have experimented with extracting the data with slices, but have not been successful. Any thoughts on this?

```
import sys
import mysql.connector
from datetime import datetime
try:
    cnx2021 = mysql.connector.connect(user='xxxx', password='xxxx', host='xxxxxxx', port='3306',
        database='avd_032021', autocommit=True)
    cursor2021 = cnx2021.cursor(buffered=True)

except mysql.connector.Error as e:
    print("Error opening avd_032021 table", e)
    sys.exit(1)

try:
    cnx2022 = mysql.connector.connect(user='xxxx', password='xxxxxxxx', host='xxxxxxxx', port='3306',
        database='avd_032022', autocommit=True)
    cursor2022 = cnx2022.cursor(buffered=True)

except mysql.connector.Error as e:
    print("Error opening avd_032022 table", e)
    sys.exit(1)

i = 0
now = datetime.now()
date_time = now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
print("date and time:", date_time)
avd_032021_Query = "select voter_id, birth_date from avd_032021"
try:
    cursor2021.execute(avd_032021_Query)
    for row in cursor2021:
        update_avd_032022_query = "UPDATE avd_032022.birth_date from %s where avd_03022.voter_id = %s"
        t1 = (row['birth_date'], row['voter_id'])
        try:
            cursor2022.execute(update_avd_032022_query)
        except mysql.connector.Error as e:
            print('error', )
            break
except mysql.connector.Error as e:
    print("Error reading data from MySQL table", e)
    sys.exit(1)

finally:
    print("Total number of records updated in table: ", i)
    if cnx2021.is_connected():
        cnx2021.close()
        cursor2021.close()
        print("MySQL cnx2021 is closed\n")
    if cnx2022.is_connected():
        cnx2022.close()
        cursor2022.close()
        print("MySQL cnx2022 is closed\n")
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By default, each row returned by a `mysql.connector` cursor will be a `tuple`.  However tuple element are accessed by their index (position in the row) rather than column name.

Either access by index:

```py
t1 = row[1], row[0]
```

or declare the cursor as a [DictCursor](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursordict.html), and access by column name

```py
cur = conn.cursor(dictionary=True)
...
t1 = (row['birth_date'], row['voter_id'])
```